Join two tables in SQL with date condition
In the first table, I have client number, start date and other columns:



Client number
start date
other1
other2




xyz
2024-04-01
values10
values20


abc
2024-01-02
values11
values21


ert
2024-01-03
values12
values22



In the second table, I have information about client bank account for everyday:



Date
Client number
account balance




2024-03-01
xyz
500.0000


2024-04-01
xyz
1000.0000


2024-04-02
xyz
1000.0000


2024-04-03
xyz
1200.0000


2024-04-01
abc
2200.0000


2024-04-02
abc
2300.0000


2024-04-03
abc
2400.0000



I want to join table 1 and table 2 to get information about client account from the start date from table 1.
For example client xyz has start date 2024-04-01, so in my result set, I want to have:



Date
Client number
account balance




2024-04-01
xyz
1000$


2024-04-02
xyz
1000$


2024-04-03
xyz
1200$


2024-04-02
abc
2300$


2024-04-03
abc
2400$



For client xyz I don't want information before 2024-04-01, and for client abc, I don't want information before 2024-04-02.
Problem is that I don't know what conditions to provide to limit client in the second table in relation to the start date.
I do not know how to build key to join tables with date condition

Maybe this fiddle will help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/WL8ON_Ff

Please edit your question to include a tag for the RDMS you are using (Sql-Server, MySQL, Oracle,..)

I think this will provide the limits you want
WITH LimitedData as
(
  SELECT * 
  FROM SecondTable
  WHERE [Date] Between '2024-1-1' and '2025-1-1' --restrict data from 2024 only
  AND  [client number] in ('abc','xyz') --restrict to short list of clients being investigated
)
Select f.*, s.[date], s.[account balance]
FROM FirstTable f
INNER JOIN LimitedData s ON f.[client number]=s.[client number]
WHERE s.[Date] >= f.[Start date]
ORDER BY f.[client number], s.[Date]

fiddle

It looks ok but in my second table i have a lot of data (many clients, from long time) so i think i should limit this data to clients and date from first table befor join is make.
And in final table i want all columns from the first table.
The question is how to select date from secon table to put them condiotion to limit clients.

Edited to use LimitedData CTE and use table alias on all columns.

@Kings2407 In your question, the expected result contains only columns of table2 and it is absolutely unclear if/why you need table1 at all in your query. Now in your comment, you suddenly say your result should also include columns from table1. Please think about what you really want to do and then edit your question accordingly. People can't help you if you don't know or don't say what you want to do.

Unless you know some filter criteria in advance, the database should figure out which table is larger and which is smaller and build the query plan accordingly. Also looks like you may want cumulative SUM("account balance") OVER (PARTITION BY "client number" ORDER BY "date" ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) in the outer query.
